# How to create the following design using Swift UIKit?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I have an app that needs this design to be added. I was wondering how to create this design in a table view. I need this design to be shown on a cell of tableView. I was thinking of adding collection view in the tableview cell and add collection view cell for the image but not sure about how to add the ‘+’ button. Also the spacing between the image and the + needs to be same as well. How can this be achieved? The images could more than 3 as well sometimes.

[image]

Comment: UIStackView maybe

Comment: You can add image and + in same cell and can show hide + as per requirement
and width of cell range given as view/3

Comment: What is the behavior of 'three items group' when you scroll? Do they stack and always go together? Or is it just a list that is nested inside a scrollView and can be scroll infinity? I'm thinking about a view with a horizontal stack inside which contains a scrollView for these items.

Comment: I was thinking of a horizontal list that scrolls to the right. There will be more than three items in the list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create uiCollectionView and set scrolling to Horizontal Hide plus image in last cell. you can set minimumlinespacing and minimumsectionspacing to very small.